# How is the supply/demand calculated?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

In this [Minimum Cost Flow tutorial](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=minimumCostFlow1) given on TopCoder, the vertices of the graph had supply/demand values. How were they calculated? I couldn't figure out from the graph given.

Comment: They are not calculated, they are a part of the input.

Comment: @svinja what do they represent exactly?

Comment: Supply (demand is just negative supply) means that the vertex "creates" that amount. So the sum of edge values going into the vertex + supply of the vertex must = sum of values going out of the vertex. It is the same for demand, except the number is negative, so more comes in than comes out. They are a constraint on the problem - only those solutions where sum_in + supply = sum_out holds for each vertex are valid. So you are looking for the best solution *among those*.